# Wordpress permissions

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." when visiting this page from the admin menu /wp-admin/edit.php?page=edit.php  But, if I take out the parameters at the end, it works "/wp-admin/edit.php"  Also getting it on "/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&page=edit.php?post_type=page"

Any ideas?  I've been all over google, but had little luck.

Answer (score 0):

Step one when you run into permissions/access denied errors is to disable plugins one at a time. I suspect you have a user levels/permissions-related plugin installed that's interfering. When you narrow it down to the plugin you can investigate that further.